# jquery not working after getting a content from div

Tags: jquery

I have created a page, in that - after loading a content the jquery is not working properly.

Problem :

- Initially i have a div "content" which having some text
- by clicking a button some content will load into the div "content" from div "temp" using 
  `$("#content").html($("#temp").html())`
- After loading this content the functionality of jquery (which i have already written in the new content) is not working.
- Why its happening like this, its working fine in mozilla firefox but not IE, some times some unwanted values are appending into the new content tags
  such as **done10="12"

  jQuery123654067531="18"

  jQuery123654067531="19"**

Please clear this problem.

Comment: By not working you mean that you cannot use the selector engine? or maybe the jQuery functions magically disappear. #NEED_MORE_INFO

Comment: Praveenjayapal, use the formatting tips to the right of your post-box next time you attempt to format your code/question.

Comment: I mean, after loading the new content. The onclick or hover events in the new content is not working through jquery.

Comment: you mean, you bind the onclick event or hover events to the content within "#temp"? It seems normal that jquery cannot locate the content becoz the DOM was changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this instead, it might solve your problem:

```
$("#content").append($("#temp"));
```

Let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you're binding events to objects in jQuery using .bind() or .click(), etc., try the new ".live()" function instead.  If you add more classes of similar, they too will now get the events attached to them.

Comment: How to use this live() function - please explain

Comment: instead of say $(".something").bind("click", function(){})  use $(".something").live("click", function(){})  so that way anytime another DOM objectis added that also satisifies the selector ".something", it also gets the click event added to it.